# Finding information within a SQL string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query (sql-server) in which I am trying to pull information out of a string.
The table has 3 fields (Key1 = order number, datestamp = date only, and logtext = string).

What I want is the key1, datestamp, and info from the string.  I need some of the data after and including "Sales Reps:"  (example: "Sales Reps: DSCANTL1 -> BDENNIK1").  I have what I need in the "salesreps" column shown below in the query, however if there are multiple cases of "Sales Reps" occurring within the logtext column, I want to display each one also.
I also want the 1st occurrence of a timestamp (##:##:##) before "Sales Reps:" and also the name of the rep just before that timestamp.
As given in my data, sometimes there is not a timestamp right before "Sales Reps:" and sometime there is one.

Here is an example of the data within the table.

```
Key1    datestamp               logtext
337316  2013-01-15 00:00:00.000 JWebb   10:41:19 Sales Reps: ARCHITE1 -> BDENNIK1
338644  2013-01-28 00:00:00.000 TWert    10:21:26 Sales Reps: PHEISSE1 -> PHEISSE2
305699  2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 JDickey  11:24:27 Status: no -> yesJDickey  11:25:03 SalesReps:  -> NOREP JDickey  11:25:08 Status: yes -> no
360429  2014-02-10 00:00:00.000 TThomas  15:51:01 Need By: 02/20/14 -> 02/14/14 Ship By: 02/20/14 -> 02/14/14 BOatman  15:53:27 Sales Reps: TCONNOR1 -> TCONNOR1~DSIDES1
347094  2013-07-12 00:00:00.000 LLilley  10:58:07 Amount: 864 -> 876.5 Order Amount: 864 -> 876.5 LLilley  10:58:08 Total Number Releases: 2 -> 3 Total Number Releases: 3 -> 4 Sales Reps: BBARBER -> LDODGE1
337319  2013-01-15 00:00:00.000 JWebb   10:25:20 Sales Reps: ARCHITE1 -> BDENNIK1 Sales Reps: BDENNIK1 -> ARCHITE1 338524   2013-01-28 00:00:00.000 TLong    12:01:54 Sales Reps: DESIGNM1-> SPARTAN1 LLilley  11:59:07 Sales Reps: SPARTAN1 -> TKELLEY1
```

Here is what I have already for my query:

UPDATED 2/14/2014:

```
    ;WITH cteChanges as
(
select      Key1, DateStamp
            ,logtext
            ,Substring(logtext,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',logtext),35) salesreps
            ,Substring(logtext,PATINDEX('%New Record%',logtext),10) newOrNot
            ,(len(logtext) - len(replace(logtext,'Sales Reps:',''))) / LEN('Sales Reps:') cnt
            ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(Logtext, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',logtext)))
                    ,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(Logtext, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',logtext)+1))),8)) ChangeTime
            ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(Logtext, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',logtext)))
                    ,CHARINDEX('||',REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(Logtext, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',logtext))))-1)),0,10) ChangePerson

FROM        chglog (nolock)

WHERE       identifier = 'OrderHed' and company ='EII' and tablename = 'OrderHed'
            and Logtext like '%Sales Reps:%'
            and Datestamp >= '01/01/2013'
            and rtrim(Left(LogText,9)) <> 'manager'

            --and Substring(logtext,PATINDEX('%New Record%',logtext),10) <> 'New Record'
)

SELECT      Key1 OrderNum
            ,DateStamp
            --,logtext
            ,SUBSTRING(salesreps,1,PATINDEX('%-%',salesreps)) + Substring(salesreps,PATINDEX('%>%',salesreps)
                    ,CASE WHEN (convert(int,charINDEX(char(10),Substring(salesreps,PATINDEX('%>%',salesreps),10))-1)) < 0 THEN 10 ELSE 
                    (charINDEX(char(10),Substring(salesreps,PATINDEX('%>%',salesreps),10))-1) END ) salesreps
            ,ChangePerson
            ,ChangeTime
            ,cnt TimesSalesPersonChanged
            --,newOrNot

FROM        cteChanges

ORDER BY    DateStamp, Key1
```

Comment: string manipulation of this magnitude will be more suited for CLR.

Comment: Does the text in the 'logtext' field have tabs in it? For example, in that last record - "...ARCHITE1 338524   2013-01-28..." is that long space before the timestamp actually stored as a tab in the database?

Comment: @Ruslan There are "Char(10)" line feeds in there

Comment: Then you can separate the separate "events" from one row using that character... And we know for a fact that each of these "events" is prefixed by a line break? That would make it so much easier.

Comment: If you can set up an SQL Fiddle with the data (including the line breaks), I will be happy to write a query for you. I'd set up the Fiddle myself but I don't have the raw original data (with the line breaks, etc.) and don't want to make a mistake.

Comment: I updated my query.  I was able to get the person who made the change and the time of the first time which "Sales Reps:" occurred, but not each occurrence of it in the string.

Comment: The best way is to create a temporary table (table variable) and then just parse the data into there, where each line (beginning with a timestamp) will be a separate row. Then query that temporary table, which will be much easier. I'll try to come up with an example.

Comment: This is a start (with my attempt to guess how your data actually looks)... I split the logs into separate rows by timestamp, now working on a way to get the sales reps' names out of those strings. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5940/3

Answer (score 0):

I was able to modify your query to make it return the Sales Reps entries as separate rows (at least those which are prefixed by the timestamp).

This should put you on the right track. My ability to debug this was limited because I don't have the data (or the schema) in its original form, but it should solve the problem you originally had with the CTE just seeing the first "Sales Reps" entries.

To get this to run, you will first need to create this function:

```
 create function dbo.SplitString 
    (
        @str nvarchar(4000), 
        @separator char(1)
    )
    returns table
    AS
    return (
        with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
            select 
                1, 
                1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str)
            union all
            select
                p + 1, 
                b + 1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
            from tokens
            where b > 0
        )
        select
            p-1 zeroBasedOccurance,
            substring(
                @str, 
                a, 
                case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE 4000 end) 
            AS s
        from tokens
      )
    GO
```

Then, this is the new version of your query (I commented out & deleted some of the original stuff you had in here because some of the columns were missing and some of it was throwing errors, but that is most likely because of differences in my test schema).

```
    ;WITH cteChanges as
(
select      l.Key1, l.DateStamp
            ,l.logtext
            ,Substring(m.S,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',m.S),35) salesreps
            ,Substring(m.S,PATINDEX('%New Record%',m.S),10) newOrNot
            ,(len(m.S) - len(replace(m.S,'Sales Reps:',''))) / LEN('Sales Reps:') cnt
            ,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(m.S, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',m.S)))
                    ,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(m.S, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',m.S)+1))),8)) ChangeTime
            ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(m.S, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',m.S)))
                    ,CHARINDEX('||',REVERSE(substring(REPLACE(m.S, CHAR(10), '|'),0,PATINDEX('%Sales Reps:%',m.S))))-1)),0,10) ChangePerson

FROM        chglog (nolock) l
  cross apply dbo.SplitString(replace(l.logtext, char(13), ''), char(10)) m
WHERE       m.S like '%Sales Reps:%'

            --and Substring(logtext,PATINDEX('%New Record%',logtext),10) <> 'New Record'
)

SELECT      Key1 OrderNum
            ,DateStamp
            ,logtext
            ,SUBSTRING(salesreps,1,PATINDEX('%-%',salesreps)) + Substring(salesreps,PATINDEX('%>%',salesreps)
                    ,CASE WHEN (convert(int,charINDEX(char(10),Substring(salesreps,PATINDEX('%>%',salesreps),10))-1)) < 0 THEN 10 ELSE 
                    (charINDEX(char(10),Substring(salesreps,PATINDEX('%>%',salesreps),10))-1) END ) salesreps
            --,ChangePerson
            --,ChangeTime
            --,cnt TimesSalesPersonChanged
            --,newOrNot

FROM        cteChanges

ORDER BY    DateStamp, Key1
```

My main change was to add the `CROSS APPLY` clause in there to split the string into separate rows based on the line terminator.

See the full SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8a67/11

Also, see here for my original attempt to do it a different (possibly easier?) way: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5940/3